# APEX 5: Calling an application process using a dynamic action

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

0 with a 12c cdb.
I have an Application Process that have created under Shared Components (Set_JD), that converts a date(:P1_SDate) & a number(:P1_SP) into a 2dp Julian date (:P1_SJD).

I've created a Change Event dynamic action on :P1_SP.  With a True/execute-plsql action to return the Julian date into item :P1_SJD. Plsql:

BEGIN

:P1_SJD := Set_JD (:P1_SDATE, :P1_SP);

END;

I get ORA-06550, Set_JD must be declared.

What am I doing wrong?

Unfortunately the Set_JD code is used lots so really need to get past this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank I'll give it a go. – SamM 4 hours ago   
     
As an aside if not for common plsql, what is the Application Processes section for? – SamM 4 hours ago  
     
Unfortunately after making Set_JD a DB side function I am now getting...."PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'Set_JD'. As far as I can see the data types are correct (date format : DD-MON-RR). Do I need to do something at either end to ensure the format is passes correctly?

Answer (score 0):

SET_JD should not be an application process within the APEX framework. It should be a function in the database.

BEGIN
  :P1_SJD := Set_JD (:P1_SDATE, :P1_SP);
END;

will be parsed as dynamic sql by the framework and translates to something like

{bind variable 1} = function ({bind variable 2}, {bind variable 3})

Comment: Thank I'll give it a go.

Comment: As an aside if not for common plsql, what is the Application Processes section for?

Comment: Unfortunately now getting...."PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'Set_JD'.    As far as I can see the data types are correct  (date format : DD-MON-RR).  Do I need to do something at either end to ensure the format is passes correctly?

Comment: If you declared the first parameter of your function as a date, you should call l=it like BEGIN :P1_SJD := Set_JD (to_date(:P1_SDATE,'dd-MON-RR'), :P1_SP); END;     This is because your bind variable is implicit varchar2

Comment: You declare an application process to use it as an "on demand" process withing javascript. You should look at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11947/bldr_app_proc.htm#HTMDB04010